# text cursor not updating in contenteditable span within div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The text cursor position was not updating while editing a `<span>` element within a `<div>` element so I decided to post this Q & A just in case anyone else ran into the same problem. Why is the text cursor not updating it's position? It updates fine when it is not wrapped in a `<div>` element. Take a look at the sample code below. The text cursor seems to "freeze" at position 1 (or after the first letter in the `span`).

**Notes:**

- The `<span>` element has `contenteditable="true"`.
- `contenteditable` is not set on the `<div>` element.

```js
$('.editableSpan').on('click keydown', function(e) {
  if ($(this).css('background-color') !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
  $(this).text('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a div with <span class="editableSpan" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: rgb(250, 197, 28);">an editable span</span>.</div>

<span class="editableSpan" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: rgb(250, 197, 28);">This is an editable span</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix to this issue is setting `display: inline-block;` to the `<span>` element. However, I am not sure as to why this works. Please feel free to add to this Q & A to describe why this works. Thanks.

```js
$('.editableSpan').on('click keydown', function(e) {
  if ($(this).css('background-color') !== 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)') {
    $(this).css('background-color', '');
  $(this).text('');
  }
});
```

```css
.editableSpan {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>This is a div with <span class="editableSpan" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: rgb(250, 197, 28);">an editable span</span>.</div>

<span class="editableSpan" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: rgb(250, 197, 28);">This is an editable span</span>
```